# Cannot rename logical filename in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server 2012 and I need to rename the logical file name of a DB.

If I run the code below I get the following results.

[image]

```
 SELECT * FROM (
       --  OR select indented code to see all databases and perfrom the check manually
       SELECT d.Name as DBName, m.name as LogicalName, --m.physical_name,
       Left(Right(m.physical_name,Len(m.physical_name)-41),Len(m.physical_name)-45) as PhysicalFileName,
       recovery_model_desc as BackupType
       FROM sys.master_files m 
       inner join sys.databases d 
       ON (m.database_id = d.database_id) 
       WHERE d.database_id > 6

) as DatabaseData 
WHERE backuptype != 'Full'
or DBName != LogicalName and LogicalName != PhysicalFileName
```

The Logical filename is currently 'ExternalWebsiteDemo_log' which is wrong so I ran

```
ALTER DATABASE ExternalWebsite MODIFY FILE (NAME=N'ExternalWebsiteDemo_log', NEWNAME=N'ExternalWebsite_Log')
```

which returns

> MODIFY FILE failed. File 'ExternalWebsiteDemo_log' does not exist.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try taking the database offline first?

Comment: Did you `USE MASTER` when you were running `ALTER DATABASE`?

Comment: No I didn't use master

Comment: no the quotes don't matter it still fails

Answer (score 2):

I have run test and can not reproduce the problem, note that I'm including `USE MASTER`

```
use master

select database_id
        ,DB_NAME(database_id) as DatabaseName
        ,name as FileLogicalName
from sys.master_files
where DB_NAME(database_id) = 'TestDb';

Alter database testdb modify file ( name ='TestDemoDb_log', NewNAME = 'TestDb_log')

select database_id
        ,DB_NAME(database_id) as DatabaseName
        ,name as FileLogicalName
from sys.master_files
where DB_NAME(database_id) = 'TestDb';
```

[image: Results]